# How to create a Custom Form in CRM without HTML5, Silverlight or the built-in form editor

Tags: c#, html, silverlight, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I've been searching for this answer for a while, and it lead me to [Silverlight](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328358.aspx) , but Microsoft says it's there for backwards compatibility, and recommends using the Web technologies as a resource you can use in the [built-in form editor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531185.aspx) that comes within the Dynamics CRM Web Application.

Is it possible to embed a custom form of some kind into the CRM for more complex bussiness logic other than creating a HTML5 /Javascript page with calls to the REST services.... or [programming a XAP file](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crminthefield/archive/2011/06/23/how-to-create-a-silverlight-web-resource-that-interacts-with-crm-2011-forms.aspx) with C# in Silverlight which is going on the path of deprecation ?

I'm using MS Dynamics CRM 2013 on-premises.

Has anyone achieved this by using any other tools or frameworks ?

Is there a Solution (like the Ribbon Workbench) that will allow us to do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing that I've seen is the use of iframes or url links that point to ASP.NET MVC, Web Forms, or any other server-side web technology. The drawbacks of this approach are that you have to maintain that set of code outside of CRM, and you cannot include that functionality in a CRM solution directly.

I agree with not using Silverlight due to the fact it doesn't work in all browsers, but I have had a lot of success doing HTML5/JavaScript pages using JavaScript frameworks like AngularJS with help from CSS frameworks like Bootstrap. This way, you can bundle up all your functionality into a CRM solution, and properly manage deployment to other environments with relative ease.

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: That's a fine solution, that we are considering, but we are not (at least right now)  fluent in web application development, that's why we are looking for something else, however, I'm curious, do you use the same web server (IIS in this case) for the custom web app? How has this worked for you?

Comment: I've had success with using the same server or a different server. Depends on the nature of the application.